# Django increment one 'hit' for views in the current day

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-models, django-views

I'm starting to learn django so I'm trying to do a little project of mine, nut I can't break through this step:

I'm trying to check how many views a certain page has.
These are my models:

```
class Significado(models.Model):
    nome = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    significado = models.TextField()
    pub_date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    hits = models.IntegerField(default=0)


class Ip(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30, default=None)
    ip = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    view_date = models.DateField(default=None)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.ip
```

and my view is this:

```
def nomes(request, name):
    #mostra o nome que esta no url /significado/<nome>
    nameSearch = Significado.objects.get(nome__iexact = name)
    sig = nameSearch.significado
    todayDate = datetime.date.today()

    ipUser = request.META.get('REMOTE_ADDR')

    try:
        ipSearch = Ip.objects.filter(name__iexact = name,
            ip__iexact = ipUser, view_date=todayDate)
        if ipSearch:
            nameSearch.hits = nameSearch.hits + 1

    except:
        novoUser = Ip()
        novoUser.name = name
        novoUser.ip = ipUser
        novoUser.view_date = todayDate
        novoUser.save()
        nameSearch.hits += 1

    ipSearch = Ip.objects.filter(name__iexact = name,
            ip__iexact = ipUser, view_date=todayDate)

    return render(request, 'nome.html', {'nome':name,
        'significado':sig,
        #'data': ipSearch.view_date,
        'ip':ipUser,
        'lista':ipSearch,
        'count':nameSearch.hits,
    })
```

What I want to do is:
-If aanyone views a certain page I'll get his ip;
-then I check if it is an ip that I've stored in the current day;
-If it is, don't increment one 'hit' on Significado;
-If the ip hasn't viewed that page in the current day, increment one 'hit' and store that ip with the current date.

It is one of my first questions here, so I apologize for any mistake!

Thanks!

Comment: what is your problem?

Answer (score 1):

So you saved your IP (novoUser) object with

```
novoUser.save()
```

but you did not save your Significado(nameSearch) object with

```
nameSearch.save()
```